# Postmarkapp sending email using template PHP class

Tags: php, api, email, postmark

I am trying to send a email using postmarkapp api in php, I have managed to get it to send plain emails. I have uploaded the class to the same directory as index.php but the 'use' function seems to give me a error which is out of my knowledge.

**Error:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /public_html/index.php on line 5
```

**Index.php**

```
// Import the Postmark Client Class.
use Postmark\Models\PostmarkAttachment;
use Postmark\PostmarkClient\.php;

// Create Client
$client = new PostmarkClient("MY API KEY - CENSORED");

// Make a request
$sendResult = $client->sendEmailWithTemplate(
  "sender@example.com",
  "recipient@example.com", 
  TEMPLATEID-CENSORED,
  [
  "product_name" => "product_name_Value",
  "name" => "name_Value",
  "action_url" => "action_url_Value",
  "username" => "username_Value",
  "sender_name" => "sender_name_Value",
  "product_address_line1" => "product_address_line1_Value",
  "product_address_line2" => "product_address_line2_Value",
]);
```

**Same directory Postmark/ I have this class (official class)**

https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-php/tree/master/src/Postmark

Thanks for taking the time to read, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Obviously I have censored my template ID and API key.

Comment: Do I have to run composer require wildbit/postmark-php in command line?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 'use Postmark\PostmarkClient;' instead of 'use Postmark\PostmarkClient.php;'